# Autofac Named Services and Dynamic Instantiation not working

Tags: autofac, named-instance

I have an object graph as,

```
Client -> Handler -> HandlerSettings
```

and my app has multiple `Client`s with different `HandlerSettings`s.

```
// instances
Client1 -> Handler1 -> HandlerSettings1
Client2 -> Handler2 -> HandlerSettings2
...
```

Autofac's [dynamic instantiation](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html?highlight=iindex#dynamic-instantiation-func-b) for [named services](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services) is not working. I can get it to work with just named services and skipping dynamic instantiation, but wanted to know why it fails and, what are my options?

For example, with,

```cs
    public class Depy1
    { }

    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1(Depy1 depy1)
        { }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        public Class2(Func<Depy1> depy1) // dynamic instantiation
        { }
    }
```

and DI as,

```cs
    var named = "bork!";
    builder.RegisterType<Depy1>()
        .Named<Depy1>(named)
        .InstancePerDependency();

    builder.RegisterType<Class1>()
        .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<Depy1>(named))
        .InstancePerDependency();

    builder.RegisterType<Class2>()
        .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<Depy1>(named))
        .InstancePerDependency();
```

and resolution as,

```cs
    var class1 = container.Resolve<Class1>(); // works
    var class2 = container.Resolve<Class2>(); // throws!
```

the `class2` resolution throws `DependencyResolutionException` as,

```
    Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
      HResult=0x80131500
      Message=None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Example.Class2' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
    Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Func`1[Example.Depy1] depy1' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Func`1[Example.Depy1])'.
      Source=Autofac
      StackTrace:
       at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context)
       at Example.Program.<Showcase>d__2.MoveNext() in D:\work\client\samples\Example\Program.cs:line 175
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at Example.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() in D:\work\client\samples\Example\Program.cs:line 34
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at Example.Program.<Main>(String[] args)

      This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
        [External Code]
        Example.Program.Showcase(Autofac.IContainer, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot) in Program.cs
        [External Code]
        Example.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs
        [External Code]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `ResolvedParameter.ForNamed`, you need to use the *actual* type in the constructor.  That means that instead of `ForNamed<Depy1>(...)`, you need to specify `ForNamed<Func<Depy1>>(...)`, changing your registration of `Class2` to:

```cs
  builder.RegisterType<Class2>()
        .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<Func<Depy1>>(named))
        .InstancePerDependency();
```